# sql "between statement" not working with spring

Tags: java, mysql

I have this sql which works fine(the result is given) when I execute the statement via the sql manager console.

```
SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT s.*, @rank
                := @rank + 1 rank
                FROM
                quiz.score s, (SELECT @rank := 0) init
                ORDER BY points DESC
                ) s
                WHERE rank BETWEEN (select count(id) from score)-(10) AND (select count(id) from score)
                ORDER BY rank;
```

If I try to execute the script via `spring` the result is always empty:

```
public List<Score> loadAllScoreLast(String pFrom, String pTo) {
        return createJdbcTemplate().query(mLAUSFT, new Object[] { pFrom, pTo },
                mScoreMapper);
    }
```

`pFrom` is in this case `(select count(id) from score)-(10)` and `pTo` is `(select count(id) from score)`

I think I include `pFrom` and `pTo` the wrong way.

That is the original sql:

```
SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT s.*, @rank
                := @rank + 1 rank
                FROM
                quiz.score s, (SELECT @rank := 0) init
                ORDER BY points DESC
                ) s
                WHERE rank BETWEEN ? AND ?
                ORDER BY rank;
```

Could someone help me with that issue?

Thx in advance

Stefan

Comment: Why are pFrom and pTo strings? I guess it is some problem with the types because the rest looks valid. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45e1b/1

Comment: In another usecase(function) I set Integers for pFrom and pTo. But here I have to scroll from end of the score list. that means I dont know how much entries I have and because of that I let sql do the work with a subselect.

Comment: But maybe it doesn't understand your sub-queries and treats them as strings.

Comment: yes I think that to. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Well, yes, write these in your whole sub-query, don't use placeholders unless for values (strings, ints, etc) which you really want replaced. I think you need placeholder just for the value of 10.

Comment: This question has noting to do with spring.

Comment: @peter.petrov works perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are pFrom and pTo strings? I guess it is some problem with the types and/or with the placeholders because the rest looks valid.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45e1b/1

You should check what plain SQL is generated.

I guess it might look like this (note the quotes).

```
SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT s.*, @rank
            := @rank + 1 rank
            FROM
            quiz.score s, (SELECT @rank := 0) init
            ORDER BY points DESC
            ) s
            WHERE rank BETWEEN '(select count(id) from score)-(10)' AND '(select count(id) from score)'
            ORDER BY rank;
```